# Grayscale UIView and all its sub children

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Is there a way to override the views render methods (drawRect: maybe?) to make it render itself and its subviews in gray scale?

Right now i fake this by generating a grayscale uiimage from a uiview using core graphics, and put in on top of the uiview. But i like to have the view still function with animations etc. but displayed in grayscale?

Comment: How about changing all colors and images (bg/imageview etc) to grayscale in actual views instead of adding proxy views?

Comment: Thanks Mar0ux thats a fine solution but i was hoping a more "automatic" way like if you could only change the render shader of the uiview or something like that.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but override `drawRect:`, call `[super drawRect]` and then fill with white in color blend mode.

Comment: Or alternatively - fill white, set blend mode to luminosity, then call `[super drawRect]`. anything drawn by `[super drawRect]` should now be rendered in bw.

Comment: i tried http://pastebin.com/7Mevd7HX but it just made the entire view white :) and all the sub views untouched